# Uglify the react bundle js using webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack-4

I am trying to do the Uglify of my bundle js file using below

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';

const GLOBALS = {
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'), //This global makes sure React is built in prod mode. https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html
  __DEV__: false // potentially useful for feature flags. More info: https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto#6-feature-flags
};

export default {
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'source-map', // more info:https://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html#sourcemaps and https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
  noInfo: true, // set to false to see a list of every file being bundled.
  entry: './src/index',
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist', // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(GLOBALS),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      uglifyOptions:{
        output: {
          comments: false, // remove comments
        },
        compress: {
          unused: true,
          dead_code: true, // big one--strip code that will never execute
          warnings: false, // good for prod apps so users can't peek behind curtain
          drop_debugger: true,
          conditionals: true,
          evaluate: true,
          drop_console: true, // strips console statements
          sequences: true,
          booleans: true,
        }
      },
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel']},
      {test: /(\.css)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css']},
      {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
      {test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'url?prefix=font/&limit=5000'},
      {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
      {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

i am getting the below error making build

```
ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (>) [./~/query-string/index.js:9,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using npm [`query-sting`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string) package of the latest version 6 which is written using ES6 syntax and apparently UglifyJS version which is used by your webpack doesn't support this syntax (because apparently, you're using old Webpack version?). So instead you need to instal `query-sting` version 5. You can see this info on their README page in [INSTALL section](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string#install).

But which webpack version do you use? Because if you're using latest Webpack 4 you should use [`optimization.minimize`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization#optimizationminimize) config instead which supports ES6+ syntax.